# How do I link one amp-story-page to another?

Tags: amp-html, amp-stories

So, I'm currently using AMP (amp-story) to make stories, and I'd like to know how can I put a button that switches from one page to another. E.g. a button that makes you go from page 5 to page 8 instead of page 6.

The intention is allow the user to skip some of the content. Does the amp-story allow for hidden pages as well (pages that are not accessible unless you press a button)?

Most of the events I tried showed me the "`_ is not whitelisted`" error on the console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, this is not possible.

Within AMP stories, this feature is called "branching" and is tracked in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/12183).  The specific functionality that you are asking about is the first line item mentioned in that issue: "...an AMP action... that can be used to jump to another page".

---

EDIT (April 2019):

Stories now have branching available experimentally, while still under development.  This allows user interactivity by splitting content state across different pages of the same story (see the [work in progress documentation](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/d16b3d82d6d009204d39128712b255010643a119/extensions/amp-story/amp-story.md#experimental-feature-branching)).