# How to set active an AMP Story Page?

Tags: amp-html, amp-story

I want to set the 3rd story page in an AMP Story as active so when a user visits the story then the first story page we show is the 3rd one.

I cannot find any code in the AMP documentation and it has to be a simple solution.

Can you please suggest me anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I link one amp-story-page to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852010/how-do-i-link-one-amp-story-page-to-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in development and currently available as an experiment called story branching. You can find the WIP documentation in this [pull request](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/21614/files).

Answer (score 0):

AMP stories are linear, meaning they must always start with the "cover" page.

Comment: And what if a user has already visited the first three 2 pages and when he revisitis the story we want to direct him in the unseen one? pretty much like facebook and instagram does?

Comment: Maybe you could add a text next to the story link that you added another slide? 
You could file a suggestion at the AMP Github project for AMP stories.